# how to open big commerce website into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

Is this possible to open website inside iframe ?

If not is there any possible to put our content page not found or this website is now allowing to fetch data into iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The iframe element</h1>

<iframe src="https://www.amazon.com" title="Amazon online shopping site">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some websites use the so-called [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) to prevent themselves from being embedded in iframe tags in pages served from other servers. To do this they send [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) headers in their pages, and the browsers honor them.

Amazon.com, for example, sends this header.

```
 x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

So, you won't be able to embed it in an iframe. If you try to do it you can see what happens by looking at your browser devtools console and network tabs.

Why? Because cybercreeps trying to phish web site users.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can we detect which website does not allow to embed it in an iframe ?